# Is it possible for a subfield of an ordered field to lack order?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, field-theory, order-theory

As an example, consider the field of complex numbers. The field of complex numbers contains the field of real numbers as a subfield. However, the field of complex numbers does not have an order defined on it while the field of real numbers does.

I am wondering if there is an example of the reverse, where we start with an ordered field, and have a subfield of that ordered field which is not ordered.

Comment: Try to prove that the subfield has an order.. Try to prove it by restricting the order of the large field to the small one.

Comment: I am thinking it is not possible because if we have a subfield of an ordered field that is not ordered, it would contradict the order of that ordered field that contains the subfield.

Comment: You could improve the question by writing down the axioms of an ordered field.

Answer (score 0):

(F,R) is an ordered field when F is a field and R is
a linear order of F adhering to a set of order axioms.
Let F' be a subfield of F.  F' is not ordered.
(F',R') is an ordered subfield of (F,R) when
F' is a subfield of F and R' = R $\cap$ F'×F'.

So yes, subfields of an ordered field are not ordered
while ordered subfields inherits the field's order.

The question is really sematical, a matter of definitions.

Comment: +1. That said, I think this could be written a bit clearer along the following lines: $(1)$ If $F$ is an order*able* field and $F'\subseteq F$ is a subfield of $F$, then $F'$ is an order*able* field. $(2)$ If $(F,R)$ is an ordered field and $F'$ is a subfield of $F$, then $F'$ *on its own* is not an ordered field ... but there's a canonical way to turn it into an ordered field, namely to use the restriction of the original ordering $R\cap (F')^2$.